# What does this nginx + Ruby on Rails error mean: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while reading response header from upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I've just recently taken over a Ruby on Rails project that uses a staging app and a production app. Unfortunately the person who set this up is MIA. I ran the "deploy" script (Capistrano) to deploy to the staging server, but it brought the house down

In the nginx logs I see this: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while reading response header from upstream

Not familiar with nginx. Can someone tell me what this means?

nginx.conf

```
##################
# STAGING SETTINGS
    upstream staging_mongrel {
        server 127.0.0.1:8003;
        }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  staging.removed.org;
        root /var/www/apps/staging/current/public;

        index  index.html index.htm;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect false;

            proxy_connect_timeout     90;
            proxy_send_timeout       400;
            proxy_read_timeout      3600;

            client_max_body_size     20m;

            if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                 rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
            }
            if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://staging_mongrel;
                break;
            }
         }
         error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
         location = /50x.html {
             root   html;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `nginx.conf` or the part that defines `server` ?

Comment: clearly in over my head here.

Comment: I think it's better to use unix sockets in your `upstream` statement. This way the upstream will serve the content generated by Rails, not the static content from the local server. Anyway, what there is behind the port 8003 in your case?

Comment: That is probably true. This was set up by someone else 5 years ago, and hasn't been touched much since then. I want to leave it mostly alone until I understand what's going on better. I would however love to make some needed minor adjustments to the site app, I just can't get the thing to work...

Comment: Do you know what the problem is? I guess I have to learn how mongrel works, and how nginx plays with that.

Comment: Well I see now.My first advice is to switch to Unicorn. I can provide a couple of config files from my working apps (nginx + unicorn + Rails 3) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The rails app stopped running. Not sure why. Turns out I had to start the mongrel instance.